# Recursive function Catalan triangle

Tags: recursion, memoization

I'm trying to learn how to build a recursive function. However, I'm not sure to understand how to set a "limit".

Here is what I'm trying to make.
I want a function that gives me the i,j number of the Catalan triangle. However, I have a recursion limit error. I never know how to set a limit. Is it with the 2 first values ? I thought my code was right, but it is obviously not.

```
Clear[catalan]
catalan[i, 0] = 1;
catalan[0, 1] = 0;

catalan[i_, j_] := 
 catalan[i, j] = catalan[i - 1, j] + catalan[i, j - 1] 
catalan[3, 2]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the error message given, you'll see that your algorithm eventually tries to evaluate something like `catalan[-1019-1,2]`. That's a clue to what's happening. Your algorithm doesn't provide any "cutoff" when we run off to the "left" of the triangle.

Also, `catalan[i, 0] = 1` is probably not what you wanted, since `i` isn't a pattern. This is just giving a literal definition for `catalan[i, 0]`.

Here is a walkthrough for what you might want:

- Define the initial case. You could do this very concretely with `catalan2[0, 0] = 1`, but we can also handle all of the elements at the "left edge" of the triangle:

  ```
  catalan2[_, 0] = 1
  ```
- For the next bit, we'll look at the "body" of the triangle. We won't bother with anything that goes off to the right, so we'll apply a condition. It'll look something like this, `catalan2[<args>] := <definition> /; a >= b`. The `/;` bit is how we apply a condition.

  ```
  catalan2[a_Integer?NonNegative, b_Integer?NonNegative] :=
     catalan2[a - 1, b] + catalan2[a, b - 1] /; a >= b
  ```

  Notice the constraints on the arguments. These aren't really necessary if we trust ourselves to always use integers, but they clarify the semantics. They also make it easier to define a default case (see next step). I skipped the memoization, for clarity.
- Now let's add a default. This allows us to avoid `If` in our definition, and it handles all of the "bad" cases.

  ```
  catalan2[___] = 0
  ```

Okay, put it all together (and adding the memoization for fun):

```
Clear[catalan2];
catalan2[_, 0] = 1;
catalan2[a_Integer?NonNegative, b_Integer?NonNegative] :=
 (catalan2[a, b] = catalan2[a - 1, b] + catalan2[a, b - 1]) /; a >= b;
catalan2[___] = 0
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.
The only part I'm not sure to understand is `catalan2[___] = 0`.
It seems to keep only the number without the []. However, the doc talking about the blank sequence. I'm not so sure to fully understand that part.

Comment: Put simplistically, the pattern `_` matches a single argument, the pattern `__` matches a sequence of 1 or more arguments, and the pattern `___` matches a sequence of 0 or more arguments. So, `catalan2[___] = 0` will match any expression with head `catalan1` and any pattern of arguments whatsoever. So, this part of the definition is a catch-all.

Comment: DownValues are stored and checked in a particular order, and in this case this catch-all will be checked only after the previous two definitions. So, everything on the "outside" of the triangle will be 0. Also, malformed arguments (non-integers, fewer than 2 arguments, more than two arguments) will all just result in 0.